# How to store incoming stream of data efficiently on Android?

Tags: android, database, stream, android-bluetooth, data-storage

I'm connecting an Android device to an embedded Data Acquisition system via Bluetooth.  The DAQ system will take data samples from 50Hz up to potentially 880Hz (possibly more in the future) and push it to the android device either as the data is collected or in bundles at faster sample rates.

There are plenty of examples of how to manage the Bluetooth connection, but not so much on what to do with the data.

I need to persist the data to some kind of long term storage and be able to do this continually at these higher sample rates for an extended period of time.

I know to do this off the UI thread, so no need to harp on that.  What storage medium on Android can respond fast enough to keep up with this incoming data?  Would the SQLite database be fast enough?  Seems like it would bog down fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I thought I'd throw up an answer anyway. SQLite should work. It would be a good idea to buffer the data into an array of bytes of a certain length, depending on what data exactly you are storing. Once that array is full, insert that into the SQL database and accept all new data into a new array. Once that one is full, store it to the database; and on and on like that. In this way you could achieve a sort of double-buffering. Database modification involves disk I/O; you would use the buffer because it's more efficient to write a big chunk of data to the disk than it is to write a lot of smaller chunks.